# How to speed up asp.net mvc 4 compliation and first load in development?

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working off of the stock ASP.net MVC 4 templates, and not doing anything terribly database intensive.

Every time I make a change, recompile and reload the page (i.e. refresh the page after it is fully done compiling) the initial load takes between 12-15 seconds.  If I refresh the page again again it takes .150 to load.

I do have the solution a non-SSD drive, going to my system drive, which is an SSD.  The solution consists of one mvc 4 project and one (empty) test project.

Any idea how to fix the initial slowness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the root cause of the problem was some malware that slipped through after a backup and the addition of dotCover from Jetrbrains.  I fixed the malware and uninstalled dotCover and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I followed some of the tips listed [on this site](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx), but it felt like building the temporary asp.net files to RAM disk seemed to help quite a bit.

Comment: I just tried that - I think it shaved about 1 second off of just using the SSD, bu tit doesn't fix the initial slowness.

Comment: Did you try the other suggestions in the article?

Comment: Have you turned on request tracing to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: I have not - seemingly that is not the problem though, as near as I can tell the problem lies in getting it into IISExpress (or that's how it seems to me anyway)

Comment: What kinds of changes are you making?  cshtml and aspx file changes shoulnd't require a recompile.  Are you restarting the debugger after every change or just refreshing the page?  Can you watch the resource monitor when you get the initial slowness?  Is the disk getting thrashed?  The CPU?  Improving the performance is about finding the bottleneck.

Comment: When I just refresh the page everything is fine (i.e. it takes almost no time).  It's only after I recompile.  Oddly I just testing the solution to where it came off an ssd drive and still no change.